# GetElementsByTagName returning length of 0

Tags: javascript, dom, getelementsbytagname

I want to get the url of a "a href" so to do this I would use getElementsByTagName and then iterate through the array; however, both alerts are returning 0 for the length. I know this can't be right since I saw with the developer tools that there are a hrefs and divs.

```
<html>

    <head>
        <title> Test </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
        window.location.href = "http://www.espn.com";
        var test = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
        var numTest = test.length;
        alert(numTest);
        var test2 = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
        alert(test2.length);
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Will Smith!

Comment: Are the elements before or after your JavaScript in the DOM?

Comment: Well, your currently example doesn't contain any `<a>` or `<div>` elements.

Comment: your page as no `<a>` tags or `<div>` tags ... zero is the correct answer

Comment: Does elements exist in dom before performing the operation .??

Comment: I want to get the <a> or <div> tags on espn. how would I start that?

Comment: you wont be able to do much, after changing the current page to a page that isn't the page you are on, your javascript will no longer run anyway

Comment: You need to retrieve the espn page, then parse it into HTML then you can use APIs like `getElementsByTagName` on it.

Comment: @WillSmith - you wont be able to get the a and div tags of an external page using client side code

Comment: *I want to get the <a> or <div> tags on espn.* Please clarify that **in your question itself** rather than in a comment.